# How can i move objects in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

ib2 = Button(window, text = 'click' , bg="aqua",
image = icon1 ,compound = BOTTOM)
ib2.grid(row=3, column=2 ,sticky='S')
```

#thats my code, so anyone can help???  Even if its possible to talk directly like any apps?!

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done any research. There are questions on this site about moving objects. You also haven't explained what object you want to me, and the code you posted won't run as posted.

Comment: Please provide complete (but minimal) code. Perhaps you could tell where is ```voice()``` and ```icon1``` defined. Also, AFAIK, you cannot use ```text``` and ```image``` together in a button. Only the image will be displayed.    Also, what do you want to move? The button?

Comment: @IshaanJog A button can have both `text` and `image` together if `compound` option is defined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the button, you can create a `move` function and bind it to `<B1-Motion>` event.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

root = Tk()
root.title("Move a button")
root.geometry("500x500")

def move(event):    # Move the button
    x = event.x     # X and Y coordinates for place the button in
    y = event.y
    btn.place(x=x, y=y)

btn = Button(root, text="Click me!", cursor="fleur")    # You can add other things you want
btn.place(x=10, y=10)

root.bind("<B1-Motion>", move)   # To move the button on left click drag
# I tried to use 'btn.bind()', but that doesn't work as expected...

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thnx for the answer, but i already have used an image in a button and it worked, it just doesnt move except using "side=NEWS" ,  so i just need to learn how to move it using something like this, i want it on top right "NE" side of my window

Comment: To place it in some directions, you can use ```anchor=""``` in ```pack()```. Example: ```btn.pack(anchor=NE)```. If you want to place the image to some other place, there are many ways to do that. You can use ```grid()    pack()    place()``` but there may be more.